# Rabbitmq-server won't start when rabbitmq.conf file is in /etc/rabbitmq/

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed Rabbitmq on oracle-linux and I get an error every time I place the rabbitmq.conf or rabbitmq.config or rabbitmq-env.conf file in the /etc/rabbitmq directory.  I have tried .conf without the dot.  I have reinstalled.

It works when there are no files that end in .conf or .config in the /etc/rabbitmq directory.

working in aws on an oracle linux server

Someone please give me some direction here.

Why would it fail when the config file is available?

I need the config file for tls setup.

startup_log

## BOOT FAILED

Config file generation failed 10:28:00.062 [error] Error creating /usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/generated: permission denied

## BOOT FAILED

Error description:
    rabbit:start_it/1 line 450
    rabbit:boot_error/2 line 857
    rabbit_lager:log_locations/0 line 59
    rabbit_lager:ensure_lager_configured/0 line 160
    rabbit_lager:lager_configured/0 line 167
    lager:list_all_sinks/0 line 317
    lager_config:get/2 line 71
    ets:lookup(lager_config, {'_global',handlers})
exit:generate_config_file
Log file(s) (may contain more information):

{"init terminating in do_boot",generate_config_file}

Comment: You probably have a syntax error in your file. Attach the complete file in a message to the [`rabbitmq-users`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/rabbitmq-users) mailing list.

Comment: That cant be it because it doesn't run if the config file is empty.

Comment: Why are you using an empty configuration file? What you need to do is provide complete copies of the file(s) that cause errors, as well as the complete log file that RabbitMQ generates. Without those I am just guessing as to what your problem is.

Comment: This is what is in the startup_err file                                                          
 Unable to parse erlang terms from  RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE file: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config
                                Error: eacce

Comment: `eacces` means that the file is not readable by the `rabbitmq` user. You have a permissions issue.

Comment: thank you! it was the permissions on the config file.